# Regular Expression in Python by Matches

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of numbers that I am trying to pull out of text.  Here is what I am working with:

```
Expression = r"(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)"
ExpressionResult = (re.findall(Expression, str(OriginalString)))
print('original')
print(str(OriginalString))
print('parsed')
print(str(ExpressionResult))
```

Here is my output:

```
original
['', '', '7', '', '', '', '9.2', '', '', '', '9.1', '', '', '', '9.2', '', '', '', '9.5.5', '', '', '', '9.5', '', '', '', '10.1.1', '', '', '', '10.1', '', '', '']
parsed
[('', '', '', '', '7'), ('9.', '', '', '', '2'), ('9.', '', '', '', '1'), ('9.', '', '', '', '2'), ('9.', '5.', '', '', '5'), ('9.', '', '', '', '5'), ('10.', '1.', '', '', '1'), ('10.', '', '', '', '1')]
```

It looks like the expression is being split up by groups rather than matches.  How do I get the match?

Expected output:

```
7, 9.2, 9.1, 9.2, 9.5.5, 9.5, 10.1.1, 10.1
```

Comment: Since each of the capture groups is optional, they'll match empty strings.

Comment: Why are you converting the list to a string and then using a regular expression? Just loop over the original list.

Comment: When you use `re.findall()` with a regexp that has capture groups, it returns the capture groups, not the whole matches. Make them non-capturing groups or use `re.finditer()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure why you are using regex?
Just use **list comprehension** to create new list, and if needed join the list using the `.join()` function:

```py
OriginalString = ['', '', '7', '', '', '', '9.2', '', '', '', '9.1', '', '', '', '9.2', '', '', '', '9.5.5', '', '', '', '9.5', '', '', '', '10.1.1', '', '', '', '10.1', '', '', '']

ExpressionResult = [x for x in OriginalString if x != '']
print(", ".join(ExpressionResult))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
7, 9.2, 9.1, 9.2, 9.5.5, 9.5, 10.1.1, 10.1
```

Comment: stylistically, I'd probably change `...if x != '']` to `...if x]`

Comment: stylistically I would change the variable naming scheme